# How to change the package name in AndroidFindBy annotation

Tags: java, android, selenium, annotations, appium

**Problem** : I want to run an Appium script on the same application, but different builds.

All resource-Id in the application is appended with the package name

Eg: For build **A** , username text field is - `alpha.beta.charlie.delta:id/user_name` and

For build **B** username field  `alpha.beta.charlie/user_name` , delta is removed from the package name.

I use AndroidFindBy from the page factory to locate the elements

```
    private static final PACKAGE = "alpha.beta.charlie.delta"

    @AndroidFindBy(id = PACKAGE + "/user_name")
    private MobileElement username;
```

Where **PACKAGE** is declared as constant .

Now if I want to run the script on build B, I have to change the package name every time before I trigger the execution. Which is not efficient.

I know we can't add variables to pagefactory annotations.

The only workaround I see is using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/uiautomator/UiSelector.html#resourceidmatches

Is there any other workaround where I can add the package name at compile time to bypass changing package name manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need package name as `Appium` can find element without package name in `resource id` so you can use `value` after **":id/"**. I went through this problem when I get package name change for `QA` build and `Prod` build. so try below code :

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "user_name")
private MobileElement username;
```

Now it is independent from package name and can be run on any build if `id` is `user_name` in all builds.